# Reading images from sub hard drive for tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, memory, storage

I want to run a tensorflow script that will read a large number of images. However, the images will not fit on my local disk drive so I am storing them on a remote usb drive.

I'm wondering how I will be able to read the images from the usb drive and use them to train my model if the images will not fit on my local hard drive? Will I need to read the images from the usb drive "batch_size" at a time? Or can I just read all of the images at once from the usb drive and divide them into batches as I normally would if they were stored on my local hard drive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's not recommended to load all image at once to be honest. Your usb-stick is just another path that can read in, in linux it will be stored under the /media folder in your root. Then I recommend to get all image paths in memory like this:

```
import os

folder_to_image_map = ""
image_paths = [os.path.join(folder_to_image_map, p) for p in os.listdir(folder_to_image_map)]
```

Image paths will load in all image paths from the folder provided.
Then you make a generator something like this:

```
from PIL import Image

def generator(BATCH_SIZE)
    batch = []
    for file_name in image_paths:
        img = Image.open(file_name)
        """ implement your preprocessing """
        batch.append(img)
        if len(batch) >= BATCH_SIZE:
            g_batch = batch
            batch = []
            yield g_batch
```

The generator will continue in the for loop after every call. Check out this example to see how it runs, play around with it.

```
def generator():
    ll = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
    for l in ll:
        yield l

run_gen = generator()
print(next(run_gen)) 
print(next(run_gen))

# or:
for j in run_gen:
    print(j)
```

This code is not the most efficient one, but it should work, I can't test it at the moment.

I Hopefully helped a bit, ask away if you've questions